# get the same result in two ways

Tags: java, events, jbutton, jtextfield, keyevent

I have two jtextfeilds (t1,t2) and one jbutton (b1)...

t1 - input
t2 -result
b1 - action

what I want to do is if I input for t1 --> 1+2 in t2 answer should be as 3 when I am typing.
and same time if I click the button it also should display the result as 3 in t2..

**My question - I can do this easily using two events (key press event in t1 and actionperformed event in b1). but what I want to do is I only need one event, as per the requirement I can't use two events? Plz can ant one help me?**

Comment: I don't get it. You're describing two completely different user input events: typing in the field and clicking the button. How can you respond to two events without using two events? What are the actual requirements?

Comment: requirement is mapping with the database, I just simply explain the problem.. what I simply want to do is if I type the item code in the field or If I select item code from popup list I need to set it to the t1 and get the item description to t2. but I want only one event, no two events can use

Answer (score 0):

> *"if I input for t1 --> 1+2 in t2 answer should be as 3 when I am typing"*

You can use a KeyListener

```
t1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        tResult.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2);
    }
})
t2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        tResult.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2);
    }
})
```

The above will calculate every time an update is made to either one of text fields andupdate the result the result textfield

**Edit:** with one listener

```
t1.addActionListener(new MyListener());
t2.addActionListener(new MyListener());
button.addActionListener(new MyListener());

private class MyListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        tResult.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

Or you can use an `Action`

```
Action action = new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        tResult.setText(String.valueOf(num1 + num2);
    }
});

t1.setAction(action);
t2.setAction(action);
button.setAction(action);
```

Comment: Wasn't really sure what you meant at first. I edited my answer, to include just one Listener for both text fields and Button. For the  text fields, you hit enter after you enter a number.